# How to return .class from Java method?

Tags: java

From a utility method in java I intend to return .class, but I am not sure how to achieve it. When I try with below method, It gives compilation error. Please suggest what is the correct approach ?

```
T getProviderClass(String customerType){

        switch (customerType){
            case "FACEBOOK":{
                return FacebookApi.class;
            }
            case "GOOGLE":{
                return GoogleApi20.class;
            }
            default:return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Class<?> getProviderClass()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `T` you should do it like this:

```
Class<?> getProviderClass(String customerType) {
     switch (customerType) {
          case "FACEBOOK":{
               return FacebookApi.class;
          }
          case "GOOGLE":{
               return GoogleApi20.class;
          }
          default: return null;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `java.lang.Class` as the return type.

```
Class<?> getProviderClass(String customerType){
}
```